# I am made of several smaller components

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Part 1:

> I am made of several small components, flexible and small.
>
> I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.
>
> Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.
>
> My parts are intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

Part 2:

> Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all basically clones.
>
> I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.
>
> I am composed of many, I'm pretty useless on my own;
>
> I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

**What am I?**

Note: "you" in the last line refers to the reader/user of the item in question.

Hint:

> Think sheep and grandmas.

Comment: Is there any significant difference between Part 1 and Part 2, or are they just two different verses describing the same thing?

Comment: They've just got different rhyme schemes, it's the OCD typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are you a wool sweater / a single stitch in a wool sweater?

Part 1:

I am made of several small components, flexible and small.

> Wool sweaters are usually made of lots of small, knit stitches.

I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.

> After a while you take the sweater off because it gets itchy? Not sure about this one.

Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.

> Sweaters keep you warm when it's windy.

My parts are intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

> The stitches in a sweater are knotted together.

Part 2:

Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all basically clones.

> The stitches in a knit sweater are all identical.

I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.

> Sweaters come in lots of colors.

I am composed of many, I'm pretty useless on my own;

> A single knit stitch is useless.

I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

> A single stitch is useless without someone knitting it together with lots of other stitches.

Comment: DING DING DING! Two logic points aren't as intended, though. The opponent is cold weather, and the truly-nothing is meant to be when somebody puts the sweater on, it becomes meaningful and useful! Way to go!

Comment: Thanks, this was my first attempt at answering something on puzzling. :D

Comment: Well, welcome! I remember my first time...15 days ago.. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think it could be

> A flag

I am made of several small components, flexible and small.

> Made of several strands of colored fiber

I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.

> Flags are used as a symbol for having conquered an opponent

Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.

> Flag flapping in the wind

I'm intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

> Fibers intertwined that will stick together

Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all pretty much clones.

> All flags have the same format and many look alike

I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.

> Self explanatory

Though I am composed of many, I'm truly useless on my own;

> A flag on its own is useless: it needs a flagpole

I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

> Humans invented flags so you wouldn't exist without us

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer-sorry. "Leave" was not meant to be converted into a pun. Though I love them, I wouldn't use them to make a question THAT convoluted. Also, though ants can stick together, they aren't exactly "intertwined." Nice try, though!

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit any more after the OP's latest edit to make the riddle less broad.

Comment: New guess to fit OP's edit

Comment: So close, but "you" still only pertains to about 1 person.

Answer (score 4):

My thought was

> electrical cables.

*I am made of several small components, flexible and small.*

> Many smaller wires, and other electronical components, go into a big cable.

*I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.*

> Not sure about this line.

*Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.*

> Cables between pylons are quite thin but they aren't broken by the wind.

*My parts are intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.*

> Many wires intertwined together. (This line was what made me think of cables as the solution.)

*Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all pretty much clones.*

> One wire is much the same as another.

*I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.*

> Wires are usually colour-coded: earth, neutral, live, etc.

*Though I am composed of many, I'm truly useless on my own;*
*I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.*

> A wire is useless on its own, without something on either side that it can connect together.

Comment: Hi rand! Yours is the best answer I've gotten so far. However, the conquering line and the last bit are your bane. It's self explanatory with the conquer line, and the last line refers to the reader/user of the item, whereas you treated it as the other components. The question will be changed to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Part 2:
This sounds like

> Pixels on a display screen.

Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all pretty much clones.

> There are lots of pixels in a display screen and they're functionally identical.

I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.

> Pixels are red, green, or blue on most displays.

Though I am composed of many, I'm truly useless on my own;

> It takes lots of pixels to make a useful image.  One pixel isn't much use.

I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

> Even the best display isn't useful unless someone is there to see it.

Comment: Good answer, but to poke the hole that faults the logic, the pixels are only transmitters for red, green, and blue light. Other than that, this answer's flawless.

Comment: @ToTheMax:  If you're going to get all philosophical on us: what does it mean for anything to *be* any color except that it emits or reflects light of that color?

Comment: @PeregrineRook What I'm saying is, they can be any color, they can be no color. I said that these things come in all sorts of colors, and pixels are made to change colors. Plus, I've already marked something else right-why bug me about this now :P

Comment: I'm "bugging you about this now" because I believe that Joe's answer is a pretty good one — [even you say that it's "flawless" except for that one point](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43349/i-am-made-of-several-smaller-components/43357?noredirect=1#comment129992_43357) — and I challenge your rationale for saying that it's faulty.  Questions that have multiple correct answers are subject to being closed as "too broad".

Comment: In all fairness, my answer doesn't match much of part 1 (apart from perhaps the "flexible and small" part) -- but I came up with it before ToTheMax clarified that both parts are talking about the same thing.  So I wouldn't say my answer qualifies as another correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a sail?

I am made of several small components, flexible and small.

> Sails are made of thread

I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.

> It's opponent could be wind, or possibly referring to naval warfare

Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.

> Sails can be fragile, but are designed to catch wind

My parts are intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

> The threads are all sewn together

Part 2:

Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all pretty much clones.

> The threads are generally identical

I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.

> Different countries might have had different color sails to identify themselves

Though I am composed of many, I'm truly useless on my own;

> You could not move a ship with a single thread

I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

> Humans must sew them together, also a sailboat without a crew would not work very well

Comment: Sails tend to be white or black (for pirates). Good answer otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the correct answer but I've to say, it is:

> [Devastator](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Devastator_(G1)) from Transformer!

I am made of several small components, flexible and small.

> Made up of 'smaller' transformer which are flexible

I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.

> Decepticon, attack!

Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.

> Usually falls apart after a minute...

My parts are intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

> They must be wired when combined

Though I'm made of lots of parts, we're all pretty much clones.

> All transformers

I come in all sorts of colors- red, green, or blue.

> Depends on version - we usually see the one with all green but there's a 'colorful' version

Though I am composed of many, I'm truly useless on my own;

> Self explanatory

I would be truly nothing, were it not for you.

> This is doesn't fit well; there're no love story in Transformer sorry.

Comment: Lol! Definitely the funniest answer, and with a backbone to boot

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps

> a gallows rope

I am made of several small components, flexible and small.

> Rope is made of several smaller strands, each of which is more flexible than the combined piece

I conquer my opponent, it'll leave sometime after all.

> Slightly wishy-washy, but if you get hanged, you die (conquered). Got nothing for the "leave sometime after all" part though

Although I amn't mighty, I sure can take a gust.

> A gallows is outside, and the rope blows in the wind

I'm intertwined and mingled, let's stick together if we must.

> Kinda number 2 again; rope is intertwined

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit any more after the OP's latest edit to make the riddle less broad.

Comment: @randal'thor very true - it looks like the OP edited the question as I was writing my answer haha. Should I leave it here, or just delete it? Not sure what the standard approach would be :)